# Python Pandas duplicate in dataframe, take info for each combo of duplicate row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe with this structure

```
id,date,id_client,optionin,optionout
1,09/01/2017,123456,11,12
2,09/01/2017,123456,12,14
3,09/02/2017,1111111,85,45
4,09/02/2017,1111111,45,35
5,09/02/2017,1111111,35,58
6,09/01/2017,528585,1,2
7,09/01/2017,548123,37,12
8,09/01/2017,123588,117,512
9,09/01/2017,981358,116,152
```

I want to get rid of the duplicate entries in the same date on the same client.
I only want the data of the first optionin, and the last optionout in the same row, and a new column with the id of the optionout

Like this

```
id,id_end,date,id_client,optionin,optionout
1,2,09/01/2017,123456,11,14
3,5,09/02/2017,1111111,85,58
6,6,09/01/2017,528585,1,2
7,7,09/01/2017,548123,37,12
8,8,09/01/2017,123588,117,512
9,9,09/01/2017,981358,116,152
```

How can I do that? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use agg()

```
df.groupby(['id_client', 'date']).agg({'optionin': 'first','optionout': 'last'}).reset_index()

    id_client   date        optionin    optionout
0   123456      09/01/2017  11          14
1   123588      09/01/2017  117         512
2   528585      09/01/2017  1           2
3   548123      09/01/2017  37          12
4   981358      09/01/2017  116         152
5   1111111     09/02/2017  85          58
```

For the id part,

```
df1 = df.groupby(['id_client', 'date']).agg({'optionin': 'first', 'optionout': 'last',  'id': ['first', 'last']}).reset_index()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)

    id_client_  date_       optionin_first  optionout_last  id_first    id_last
0   123456      09/01/2017  11              14              1           2
1   123588      09/01/2017  117             512             8           8
2   528585      09/01/2017  1               2               6           6
3   548123      09/01/2017  37              12              7           7
4   981358      09/01/2017  116             152             9           9
5   1111111     09/02/2017  85              58              3           5
```

Comment: save one step : `df.groupby(['date','id_client'],as_index=False).agg({'optionin': 'first', 'optionout': 'last'})`:)